# Pointer to uninitialized data member

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, reference

### Is it safe to store reference/pointer on uninitialized data member?

Not use, but store at some moment of time.

I know that I have to use smart pointers. But for code simplicity I decide to give an example with owning raw pointers. Which is not very good in practice but I think good enough for example.

Here is the example of code:

```
struct Node {
    Node(Node*& node_ptr) : list_first_node_ptr{node_ptr} {}
    /* ... */
    Node*& list_first_node_ptr;
};

struct List {
    // Is this line - dangerous?
    List() : first_node_ptr{new Node{first_node_ptr}} {}
    /* ... */
    Node* first_node_ptr;

    ~List() {delete first_node_ptr;}
};
```

I initialize `first_node_ptr` with `Node` object, but pass in constructor of `Node` object still not uninitialized `first_node_ptr`.

---

**One more question:** is memory already allocated for `first_node_ptr` when I pass it, so will the reference address at `Node` constructor be valid?

I think that this example is about the same but simplified version. I'm right?

```
class Base {
 public:
    // var_ptr points to uninitialized va
    Base() : var_ptr{&var}, var{10} {}

    int* var_ptr;
    int var;
};
```

---

**P.S.**
Why when I write `(Node*)&` instead of `Node*&` I get compilation errors about incomplete type?

**P.P.S.**
Can the usage of smart pointers change the situation?

**P.P.P.S.**
@JesperJuhl asked about use case. 
The idea is to create circular linked list where every Node has a reference on Head pointer to first sentinel Node. I get this idea from **Herb Sutter in CppCon video 2016 43:00.** In video he talked about unique pointers but I give example with raw pointers, it may be become a little bit confusing.

Comment: I've asked [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50028982/is-taking-the-address-of-a-member-of-an-uninitialized-object-well-defined), though it's not exactly a duplicate.

Comment: I think `std::shared_from_this` will handle this situation better, if I understood logic properly

Comment: @Slava `std::shared_from_this` doesn't work in constructors.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux it does not have, idea is not to pass it to `Node` but return it when needed

Comment: Anyway looks like AB problem - `Node` should not have this pointer

Comment: Why would you ever want to store a `Node *&` as a member variable?

Comment: The question is about the legality of the code, not about the design of the example used to illustrate the question. Edit : Nevermind, I hadn't noticed the P.P.S.

Comment: @JesperJuhl your question is moot. It's about code conformance, not about the reason for the code.

Comment: Possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338601/can-you-bind-a-reference-to-an-uninitialized-member

Comment: @JesperJuhl I edit question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Node::list_first_node_ptr` is a reference. It doesn't care about the *value* of the referenced object, just that the referenced object *itself* actually exists. Since `List::first_node_ptr` is guaranteed to exist when `Node::list_first_node_ptr` is constructed, this is legal code.

To phrase it another way; a reference can never be null, but it can reference a pointer that is null.

It's worth noting, though, that `List::first_node_ptr` will not point to a valid object until `Node` has finished constructing. This means you can't dereference `List::first_node_ptr` or `Node::list_first_node_ptr` until the `Node` constructor has finished.

Comment: Nitpicking: _you can reference a pointer which is null_ - the pointer has an indeterminate value initially.

Comment: The one in his example does, I was just trying to keep the rephrasing simple to understand. Either way, dereferencing a null pointer or a pointer in an indeterminate state is undefined behaviour.